# How To Determine "Adjective" Or " Adverb" After The Noun?

Tags: grammar, differences, adjectives, adverbs

1. The way ahead is busy.
2. This is the only way possible.

How to determine which one "adjective" and which one "adverb" between "ahead" and "possible"?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying you think one of these words is an adjective, and one is an adverb? Why do you think this?

Comment: "Ahead" is a preposition and "possible" is an adjective.

Comment: BillJ, the OED makes no mention of *ahead* as a preposition, instead listing it as an adjective only.

Comment: Give English Language Learners SE a try, too.

Answer (score 1):

You (or possibly the teachers or the grammar you are working with) are confusing two quite different things: word class ("part of speech") and syntactic function.

As BillJ says, *ahead* is a preposition and *possible* is an adjective—that is, those are the word classes into which they are categorized.

But in your sentences both words function as modifiers of a noun. This may not be entirely clear to a learner, because neither is set before the noun it modifies, which is the ordinary position for adnominals.

- *Possible* has its ordinary sense and use. It might with propriety be set before the noun it modifies, *the only possible way*; but it is one of several adjectives which it is just as proper to set after the noun. In the case of *possible* this position is licensed by the fact that it frequently takes a following complement (eg, *possible to VERB/be VERBen*), and adjectives with following complements are required to lie after the noun they modify.
- *Ahead* is employed intransitively, without an object, and therefore acts like a complete preposition phrase. (Etymologically, in fact, it is a preposition phrase, *on head*.) It is set after the noun it modifies (*way*) because that is the ordinary position for preposition phrases: compare *the way to London*, *the way from here to there*.

Traditional grammar took "part of speech" to be the defining property of words in their syntactic context: for instance, the core function of nouns is to act as subject or object of a verb or object of a preposition, and the core function of adjectives is to modify nouns, either directly or as a predicate complement. Consequently you will often find traditional grammarians categorize entire clauses as "noun phrases" or "adjective phrases" on the basis of their syntactic function. For instance, *ahead* in this context would be categorized as an "adjective" or "adjective phrase", because it modifies *way*. In another context (eg, *We're looking ahead*) it might be categorized as an adverb.

More recent grammars, however, tend to distinguish syntactic function from internal structure and properties; *ahead* would most commonly be described as a preposition modifying *way*.

Comment: The OE entry (updated 2012) for “ahead” gives  ahead, as “adv., prep., and adj.” -- **Adv.**: 2008    “*We see two walkers up ahead.*” -- **Prep**: (with the note: rare after 17th cent.) 1633  “*In the afternoone (it being something hazye) we saw some breaches ahead vs.* and notes that later use, “***Later examples may represent the adverb, being misspellings or typographical errors for ahead of***.”
e.g. 1905 *I saw the figure of my friend ahead me, and hastened my pace to overtake him.* -- **Adj**: 1979 *All propulsion was lost and the ahead movement of the vessel slowed.*